# Roblox, Lua: UserInputService never works for me

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm using a local script, and every time I try to write code with UserInputService, it never works for me.

Here is my code: When I press and hold the "C" key, I try to set the "isPBPressed" variable to true, and when I release the key, the variable should become false. The code is made for both seats "nti1_VehicleSeat" and "nti3_VehicleSeat"

```
local UserInputService = game:GetService("UserInputService")

local mainTrain = script.Parent.Parent["81-717"]
local nti1_VehicleSeat = mainTrain.VehicleSeat
local nti3_VehicleSeat = mainTrain.VehicleSeat2

local isPBPressed = mainTrain.isPedalBditelnostiPressed

local function onKeyPress(input)
    if input.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.C and (input.UserInputState == Enum.UserInputState.Begin or input.UserInputState == Enum.UserInputState.Change) then
        if nti1_VehicleSeat.Occupant or nti3_VehicleSeat.Occupant then
            isPBPressed.Value = true
        end
    end
end

local function onKeyRelease(input)
    if input.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.C and (input.UserInputState == Enum.UserInputState.End or input.UserInputState == Enum.UserInputState.Change) then
        isPBPressed.Value = false
    end
end

UserInputService.InputBegan:Connect(onKeyPress)
UserInputService.InputEnded:Connect(onKeyRelease)
```

The code is made for both seats "nti1_VehicleSeat" and "nti3_VehicleSeat"